# Re-initializing ACE editor after navigating away

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using the [ACE editor](http://ace.ajax.org) for a web application built with Bootstrap. It hasn't been easy but I've gotten ACE to load within this framework using an iframe that loads the editor and populates it with data from a database. This works ok, but after I navigate to another page and then come back to the editing page, I get this error:

> Exposing chrome JS objects to content without **exposedProps** is insecure and deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers for more information.

If I attempt to keep a handle on the editor object, and reuse it, I get this error instead:

> NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIDOMJSWindow.setTimeout] (on ace.js, line 1)

Is there a trick to creating new editors every time I navigate back to this page? Or re-initializing the editor so that it doesn't throw an error?

Comment: That doesn't look like an ACE error. It's some kind of internal Netscape error. You aren't using ACE in a Netscape Extension or something, are you?

Comment: Running in Firefox, no weird extensions